# What is the most efficient way to click a link in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to click the first link on a pirate bay url (not for nefarious purposes, it's just a personal project) and I'm wondering whether this is the best way to do it:

```
For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links

    If ele.GetAttribute("href").Contains("magnet") Then
        ele.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

I am wondering if this is the best way to click the first magnet link on a page, I'm currently using a web browser however I want to know if it's possible to do it without? Maybe with a HTTP request or something along those lines?

****EDIT for GJKH****

I have the code like this:

```
Dim PBsource As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://pirateproxy.se/search/ubuntu/0/7/0")
MsgBox(PBsource)
```

However nothing appears in the messagebox, it's just blank, am I passing the url wrong?

****EDIT 2 ****

I have this code in my button sub:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

Dim PBsource As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://pirateproxy.se/search/ubuntu/0/7/0")
MsgBox(PBsource)

Dim strReg As String
'Regex to get a herf links
strReg = "<a\s+href\s*=\s*""?([^"" >]+)""?>(.+)</a>"
Dim reg As New Regex(strReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim m As Match = reg.Match(PBsource)
Dim magnetURL As String = ""
'Keep going while we hit regex matches
While m.Success
    If m.Groups(1).Value.ToString.Contains("magnet") Then
        'Match found, assign magnetURL and exit while
        magnetURL = m.Groups(1).ToString
        Exit While
    End If
    'Match not found, move to next match
    m = m.NextMatch()
End While


If Not magnetURL Is String.Empty Then
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
        PBsource = wc.DownloadString("magnet:?xt=urn:btih:1e4dae83371ba704d5d89e1828068ef0c4151e32&dn=Steam+OS+Official+Installer&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337")
        MsgBox(PBSource)
    End Using
Else
    MsgBox("no magnet URL found")
End If
End Sub
```

However no matter what it seems that PBSource is never being set correctly. It just results in a blank string

Comment: You can get the page, parse it using HTMLAgilityPack and then "click" the link

Comment: Your code is all over the place, see my updated answer, just copy and paste.

Comment: @GJKH Thanks, I'm out of my depth here, originally started as a project just to learn loops. Appreciate the help it works perfectly now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the HTML as a string using WebClient.DownloadString will be more efficient than using browser, then it's a case of parsing the string to get what you're after.

I'm not entirely certain how you would do go about this but in theory you could parse the data as it is downloading and then cancel the operation once you've found what you need - that's probably overkill though.

```
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
        Dim PBSource = wc.DownloadString("http://pirateproxy.se/search/ubuntu/0/7/0")

        Dim strReg As String
        'Regex to get a herf links
        strReg = "\<a.+?href=(?<q>["" '])(.+?)\k<q>.*?>([^\<]+)"
        Dim reg As New Regex(strReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Dim m As Match = reg.Match(PBSource)

        Dim magnetURL As String = ""


        'Keep going while we hit regex matches
        While m.Success
            If m.Groups(1).Value.ToString.Contains("magnet") Then
                'Match found, assign magnetURL and exit while
                magnetURL = m.Groups(1).ToString
                Exit While
            End If
            'Match not found, move to next match
            m = m.NextMatch()
        End While

        If Not magnetURL Is String.Empty Then
            Dim a = MsgBox("Would you like to open:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & magnetURL, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
            If a = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then Process.Start(magnetURL)
        Else
            MsgBox("no magnet URLS found")
        End If

    End Using
```

Comment: Just tested this with non magnet urls and works for me, you may need to remove a leading and trailing `'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, never used Regex before but I'm willing to try. What do you mean I may need to remove a leading and trailing '?

Comment: In my tests some URLs had apostrophes, so remove these - Process.Start(Replace(magnetURL, "'", ""))

Comment: The code above works out of the box though, just replace piratebayurlhere with any page that contains a magnet link.

Comment: Note that this works only for a "normal" link. If there is an "onclick" event handler which executes some JavaScript, then you'll need the original code, which invokes the "click" event.

Comment: See updated answer, setting the user agent fixes the issue of DownloadString() not getting anything.